# Forward/Inverse Dynamics Library?

Tags: ros, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to ask if there is a Forward/Inverse Dynamics Library for a robot model

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35688/forward/inverse-dynamics-library?/) by [nakagawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2541/nakagawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the recent openrave versions (0.7.x) have inverse dynamics which can be used as :

```
robot.SetDOFValues(dofvalues)
robot.SetDOFVelocities(dofvelocities)
torques = robot.ComputeInverseDynamics(dofaccelerations)
```

you can also split the contributions

```
torqueconfiguration, torquecoriolis, torquegravity = robot.ComputeInverseDynamics(dofaccelerations,None,returncomponents=True)
```

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5